# documnet.getElementById does not fetch the value . what is going wrong?

Tags: javascript

i am sure this is quite a numb question to ask and most probably the most basic one. i am just a starter for JS.

i am trying to access the value of input field by document.getElementById and it is returning null to me i am not sure why here is the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var name = document.getElementById("e_name");
            alert(name);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="e_name" value="Enter your Name"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the following code prints the value null in alert box. what is wrong?

Update :

When i use the following code.

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Enter your Name"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            alert(name);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

it prints Enter your Name but if i change the value it does not print the changed value. i would want to perform the following for validation purpose

a) holds the value of e_name in a javascript variable in the head tag

b) so that i should be able to process it for validation.

how do i do it?

Comment: document.getElementById("e_name").value;
OR $('#e_name').val();
Which is easier ;)

Comment: @benhowdle89 - I don't think the author is using jQuery

Comment: Yeah i know :) was just pointing it out and showing him that jQuery has easier markup to learn

Comment: @benhowdle89 of course using jQuery makes life easier and i should be using it but then i want to learn JS. in the later stage i would gladly go with jQuery. :)

Comment: I understand completely. I posted this Q on programmers.se: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40845/how-necessary-is-it-to-learn-javascript-before-jquery Have a read :)

Comment: Nice one. i enjoyed reading it.. thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're calling that line of script even before document object is ready!

Try this

```
<body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="e_name" value="Enter your Name"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var name = document.getElementById("e_name").value;
            alert(name);
        </script>

</body>
```

Or this in your head tag.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var name = document.getElementById("e_name");
            alert(name);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript code is executing before that HTML has loaded.  The element with `id="e_name"` doesn't actually exist in the document yet.

Answer (score 0):

function validate()   
{   
var nam=name.value;   
alert("name"+nam);   
}